# Getting back a 405 Method Not Allowed from NotFound()

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

In an ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC app, I have a View that makes an Ajax request back to a controller, the request goes through and gets to the controller where a condition is met that should return a NotFoundResult (404):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/My/AjaxAction",
    data: {
        name: name
    }
})

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AjaxAction(string name)
{
    if (/* condition */)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    //....
}
```

When testing this I get back a 405 Method Not Allowed response instead of a 404. I debugged and verified that I am hitting the `NotFound()` line. However the EndpointMiddleware is changing the response to a 405 and I don't know why:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult[1]
>         Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 404
>     info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
>         Executed action MyProject.MyController.AjaxAction (MyProject) in 2071.1794ms
>     info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
>         Executed endpoint 'MyProject.MyController.AjaxAction (MyProject)'
>     info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
>         Executing endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'

Other Ajax actions using POST in the application still work fine, it's just this one that is the problem.

Update: If I don't satisfy the condition for `NotFound()` and instead return an `Ok()` as normal, then it returns the correct response as it should. It's only 404s are that being changed to 405s.

Comment: Without tellung is what "NotFound()" does, there is nothing we can do. All we can tell is that teh Server send a HTTP Error 405.

Comment: @Christopher  [ControllerBase.NotFound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.notfound?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: what is the uri that you are sending?  Does it actually hit that action?

Comment: @TMcKeown Yes, it hits the action and returns the `NotFoundResult` as it should, then the EndpointMiddleware changes it to a 405.

Comment: There's not enough here to answer you question. This might be due to some custom error handler, but we have no code to tell if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/388

In resume you are always calling the url: `/My/AjaxAction` and you want to sometimes it returns `404` (This endpoint does not exist) and sometimes returns `200`. But it is the same route, so it will be a bit confusing for the consumers of your api. I believe that's why Asp.Net teams is doing this.

You can make a few changes to solve it.

One option is to add the name parameters on url so your url will not be always the same and you'll be able to return not found.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/My/AjaxAction/"+name,
    data: {
        // other datainfo 
    }
})

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AjaxAction(string id) // Change name to id to asp.net route understand that this parameter is in your route and not on body.
{
    if (/* condition */)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    //....
}
```

Other option is to return other type of http error. like 400

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/My/AjaxAction",
    data: {
        name: name
    }
})

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AjaxAction(string name)
{
    if (/* condition */)
    {
        return BadRequest(); // You can also add an error message or an model;
    }

    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your calling. Can you change the url to **"/My/AjaxAction/test"**
instead of **"/My/AjaxAction"**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/My/AjaxAction/test",
    data: {
        name: name
    }
})
```

Also, you can try specifing the route in HttpPost like:

```
[HttpPost("/My/AjaxAction")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AjaxAction(string id) // Change name to id to asp.net route understand that this parameter is in your route and not on body.
{
    if (/* condition */)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    //....
}
```